# Plural noun after "the last", e.g. "The last vestige/traces", should it be singular?

Tags: grammar

Sorry, if it sounds trivial, I saw people wrote "the last vestiges....." and 'the last traces ....", should it be singlar? but obviously it is more common in plural, is it a common practice or is there any rule I messed in English?

Comment: No, it should not be singular; there is no rule against using plurals.

Comment: If it were singular, it would refer to a single vestige or trace. The plural form is common, perhaps because it suggests a slower end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the "last" you can still use plural. For instance, I saw my friend 20 times this month, the last four times he appeared to be quite distant. You would use singular if you mean: he appeared normal 19 times and odd once.

Comment: Thanks, it confused me because I always think the last is really THE last, Perhaps, it is not really THE last in English.

Comment: @Peterjohan1212 But there's nothing wrong with using the singular *either*. It depends on what you're trying to emphasize. (*The last vestiges* or *the very last vestige*.)